# Scatter plot with same colour and varying colour tone based on the data frame values

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, scatter-plot

I have a dataset with data pattern for two of it's columns looks something similar to the following:

```
df[1] = [20,20,20,65,65,86,86,86...]

df[2]=[110,1520,11111,1322.......]

...
```

I'm trying to fit a model with this data set and in that process, I have to represent the data points with different colour schemes and colour intensities to understand the plot better.

This is how the plot looks like:

[image: Fit]

> The dots are the data points and the curve is the estimated fit.

and to generate this plot, I wrote the following line in my code:

```
 plt.scatter(df[1], df[3]/df[2], c=df[1])
```

Here the change in the value is only w.r.t to df[1]. But I also would like to vary the different colours intensities based on the values of df[2] by using this criteria:

> For the same values of df[1], the adjacent values of df[2] would be
> compared against each other. The highest one will get more intensity
> and the lowest get lesser intensity of the same color. Similary for
> other value of df[1], the color will change and the adjacent values
> of df[2] needs to be compared against for the color intensities.
>
> In our example for **df[1]** value = **20**, the **df[2]** values
> **110,1520 and 11111** are to be compared against each other and the highest one gets the **brightest colour tone** ( though having same colour for all these three values).

Could someone please suggest how to plot this ?

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution to your problem would be to get "buckets of colors", based on df[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nveqz.png) values

Here an example

```
df_1 = [20, 20, 20, 30, 30, 30, 40, 40, 40]
df_2= [100, 200, 1000, 100, 200, 1000, 100, 200, 1000]
```

here I am building my "buckets" of colors

```
my_lists = {}

for i in range(len(df_2)):
    if 0<1/df_2[i]<0.005:
        if 'bucket1' not in my_lists:
            my_lists['bucket1'] = ([df_1[i]], [df_2[i]], 'darkgreen')
        else:
            my_lists['bucket1'][0].append(df_1[i])
            my_lists['bucket1'][1].append(df_2[i])
    if 0.005<=1/df_2[i]<0.010:
        if 'bucket2' not in my_lists:
            my_lists['bucket2'] = ([df_1[i]], [df_2[i]], 'limegreen')
        else:
            my_lists['bucket2'][0].append(df_1[i])
            my_lists['bucket2'][1].append(df_2[i])
    if 0.01<=1/df_2[i]<0.02:
        if 'bucket3' not in my_lists:
            my_lists['bucket3'] = ([df_1[i]], [df_2[i]], 'lime')
        else:
            my_lists['bucket3'][0].append(df_1[i])
            my_lists['bucket3'][1].append(df_2[i])


for key, value in my_lists.items():
    plt.scatter(value[0], 1/np.array(value[1]), c=[value[2]])
```

the result

[image]

an update with more buckets

```
my_lists = {}
for i in range(len(df_2)):
    if 0<1/df_2[i]<0.005 and 0<df_1[i]<21:
        if 'bucket1' not in my_lists:
            my_lists['bucket1'] = ([df_1[i]], [df_2[i]], 'darkgreen')
        else:
            my_lists['bucket1'][0].append(df_1[i])
            my_lists['bucket1'][1].append(df_2[i])
    if 0.005<=1/df_2[i]<0.010 and 0<df_1[i]<21:
        if 'bucket2' not in my_lists:
            my_lists['bucket2'] = ([df_1[i]], [df_2[i]], 'limegreen')
        else:
            my_lists['bucket2'][0].append(df_1[i])
            my_lists['bucket2'][1].append(df_2[i])
    if 0.01<=1/df_2[i]<0.02 and 0<df_1[i]<21 :
        if 'bucket3' not in my_lists:
            my_lists['bucket3'] = ([df_1[i]], [df_2[i]], 'lime')
        else:
            my_lists['bucket3'][0].append(df_1[i])
            my_lists['bucket3'][1].append(df_2[i])
    if 0<1/df_2[i]<0.005 and 21<df_1[i]<31:
        if 'bucket4' not in my_lists:
            my_lists['bucket4'] = ([df_1[i]], [df_2[i]], 'blue')
        else:
            my_lists['bucket4'][0].append(df_1[i])
            my_lists['bucket4'][1].append(df_2[i])
    if 0.005<=1/df_2[i]<0.010 and 21<df_1[i]<31:
        if 'bucket5' not in my_lists:
            my_lists['bucket5'] = ([df_1[i]], [df_2[i]], 'royalblue')
        else:
            my_lists['bucket5'][0].append(df_1[i])
            my_lists['bucket5'][1].append(df_2[i])
    if 0.01<=1/df_2[i]<0.02 and 21<df_1[i]<31:
        if 'bucket6' not in my_lists:
            my_lists['bucket6'] = ([df_1[i]], [df_2[i]], 'lightsteelblue')
        else:
            my_lists['bucket6'][0].append(df_1[i])
            my_lists['bucket6'][1].append(df_2[i])
    if 0<1/df_2[i]<0.005 and 31<df_1[i]<41:
        if 'bucket7' not in my_lists:
            my_lists['bucket7'] = ([df_1[i]], [df_2[i]], 'darkred')
        else:
            my_lists['bucket7'][0].append(df_1[i])
            my_lists['bucket7'][1].append(df_2[i])
    if 0.005<=1/df_2[i]<0.010 and 31<df_1[i]<41:
        if 'bucket8' not in my_lists:
            my_lists['bucket8'] = ([df_1[i]], [df_2[i]], 'firebrick')
        else:
            my_lists['bucket8'][0].append(df_1[i])
            my_lists['bucket8'][1].append(df_2[i])
    if 0.01<=1/df_2[i]<0.02 and 31<df_1[i]<41:
        if 'bucket9' not in my_lists:
            my_lists['bucket9'] = ([df_1[i]], [df_2[i]], 'lightcoral')
        else:
            my_lists['bucket9'][0].append(df_1[i])
            my_lists['bucket9'][1].append(df_2[i])


for key, value in my_lists.items():
    plt.scatter(value[0], 1/np.array(value[1]), c=[value[2]])
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion..The dataset in my case has more entries and I need different colours for different values of df[1] and for each value of X ( df[1]), the corresponding values of df[2] needs to be compared against and then the highest value's point needs to get more intensity of the same color

Comment: so, there are two variables values df[1] and df[2] to decide the color and  their intensities respectively

Comment: @ranjith you can simply specify more buckets color. Changign in your if condition also for the range in df[1]. Check my update